# System of equations, problem about angles

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, angle

I'm solving a problem (about circles and geometric fiqures), during a project I came up with this system, and in contains all my work, I'm not be able to solve it further so I need some help.

$$
\begin{cases}
\theta_3+\theta_5+\theta_8+\theta_{11}+\theta_{13}=360\\
\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3=180\\
\theta_4+\theta_5+\theta_6=180\\
\theta_7+\theta_8+\theta_9=180\\
\theta_{10}+\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}=180\\
\theta_{13}+\theta_{14}+\theta_{15}=180\\
\theta_8+\theta_{11}+\theta_{13}=180\\
\theta_5+\theta_8+\theta_{11}=180\\
\theta_3+\theta_{13}=180\\
\theta_3+\theta_5=180\\
2\theta_1+\theta_3=180\\
2\theta_7+\theta_8=180\\
2\theta_8+\theta_{13}=180\\
\theta_9+\theta_{10}=2\theta_8\\
\theta_3=2\theta_4\\
\theta_5=2\theta_1\\
\theta_1+\theta_4=90\\
\theta_2+\theta_{15}=90\\
\theta_9+\theta_{10}=\theta_8+\theta_{11}\\
\theta_3=\theta_8+\theta_{11}\\
\theta_7=\theta_{12}\\
\theta_5=\theta_{13}\\
\theta_6=\theta_{14}\\
\theta_4=\theta_{15}\\
\theta_1=\theta_2\\
\theta_7=\theta_9\\
\theta_8=\theta_{11}
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks fo any help.

Comment: It is a system of 27 linear equations in 15 unknowns (if I counted right):  what do you know about this topic ? Additionally there is to consider that, being the unknowns angles, values differing by multiples of $2\pi$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I plugged your equations in a matrix calculator and got:

$$
\theta_{1}=\theta_{2}=30,\\
\theta_{3}=120,\\
\theta_{4}=\theta_{5}=\theta_{6}=\theta_{7}=\theta_{8}=\theta_{9}=\theta_{10}=\theta_{11}=\theta_{12}=\theta_{13}=\theta_{14}=\theta_{15}=60.
$$